# One who welcomes new challenges and new opportunities

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a person who welcomes new challenges and new opportunities for success and nothing can stop him called?

Comment: Such a person would be called *a go-getter* or *a real go-getter*.  By the way I don't think this question should be closed.  I don't think it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person could be called  **adventurous**.

> *adventurous* {[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adventurous)}
>
> Willing to take risks or to try out new methods, ideas, or
>   experiences.

The corresponding noun (adventurer) is rarely used with a corresponding meaning.

If they are really gung-ho, they might attract the metaphorical label

**buccaneer**

> *buccaneer* {[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/buccaneer)}
>
> A person who acts in a recklessly adventurous and often unscrupulous
>   way, especially in business.

Answer (score 1):

A ***[pioneer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pioneer):***

> - one who opens up new areas of thought, research, or development: *a pioneer in aviation.*
> - one who is first or among the earliest in any field of inquiry, enterprise, or progress.

The Free Dictionay

Answer (score 1):

In the financial world he would be called an **"entrepreneur"**

> - entrepreneur (noun) a person who starts a business and is willing to risk loss in order to make money [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entrepreneur)

Answer (score 0):

*Inspired* is a good one. I think however, they'll probably come to find that they were being *overly enthusiastic*.

> **enthusiastic**. adj. c.1600, "pertaining to possession by a deity," from Greek enthousiastikos "**inspired**," from enthousiazein (see enthusiasm). Meaning "pertaining to irrational delusion in religion" is from 1690s. The main modern sense, in reference to feelings or persons, "**intensely eager, rapturous**," is from late 18c. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=overly%20enthusiastic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=overly%20enthusiastic%20definition)

---

See also, "[Type A Personality](https://www.google.com/search?q=type%20a%20personality&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)"

> A temperament characterized by excessive ambition, aggression, competitiveness, drive, impatience, need for control, focus on quantity over quality and unrealistic sense of urgency. It is commonly associated with risk of coronary disease and other stress-related ailments. See also *type B personality*. –[businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/type-A-personality.html)

On a personal note, I find the un-highlighted definitions of *enthusiastic* (that connotate fanaticism) make it an extremely satisfying word to describe *type a's*.

Answer (score 0):

**ambitious**:

- having or showing a strong desire and determination to succeed
- intended to satisfy high aspirations and therefore difficult to achieve

Answer (score -1):

What is a person who welcomes new challenges and new opportunities for success and nothing can stop him called?

- An opportunist.

Comment: This it the start of what may be a good answer, but you may want to check up on some dictionary entries and reconsider. Also on this site usually the source and summary of the reference are added in an answer to compensate for link rot.